# What does `__meminit` mean in Linux Kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, x86, x86-64, linux-device-driver

**Problem**:

I ofent see `__meminit` decorator in Linux source code put in front of functions.  I am wondering what does the `__meminit` decorator mean.

Eg. In `arch/x86/mm/init_64.c`:
`static void __meminit remove_pagetable(unsigned long start, unsigned long end, bool direct, struct vmem_altmap *altmap)`

**Attempts**:

I tried to look at the definitions of the macros like

```
/* Used for MEMORY_HOTPLUG */
#define __meminit        __section(.meminit.text) __cold notrace \
                          __latent_entropy
```

But still cannot understand the usage of it.

**Follow-up Question:**

Where can Linux learner find descriptions of such macros?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Unfortunately, Linux is not very well documented, and reading the source code and building intuition is still the primary way to learn how it works.

`__meminit` is defined in [linux/init.h](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/init.h#L88) as

```
#define __meminit        __section(".meminit.text") __cold notrace \
                          __latent_entropy
```

The comment at the top of this file briefly explains how the `__init` macro is used to mark functions that are used only during initialization and that later can be discarded.
`__meminit` is a specialized version of `__init`, it marks a function that is used during memory initialization.
As the comment `/* Used for MEMORY_HOTPLUG */` before the definition of `__meminit` implies, it is used with memory hotplug.
Presumably, the kernel won't free the memory initialization functions if memory hotplug is enabled since these can be needed at any time (e.g. when a new DIMM is inserted). But it will still free other initialization functions.

It is generally not safe to call a function marked with `__XXXinit` from ordinary code (it could be no longer present) but if you are writing the code that handles the hotplugging of memory, then you know the kernel won't free `__meminit` functions and it is safe to call them (in this context).

All the `__XXXinit` macros work similarly, they put the function/variable in a section with a specific name so that the kernel can later free up it.

`__meminit` expands to:

- `__section(".meminit.text")`. This places the function in the `.meminit.text` section. It is just an ordinary section with a standardized name.
- `_cold` [expands to](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/compiler_types.h#L104) the GCC [cold](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-cold-function-attribute) attribute. It tells GCC that the function is seldom called and thus it's better to optimize it for size rather than for speed.
- `notrace` is used to [mark the function as not ftraceable](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/compiler_types.h#L165). The whole machinery is a bit involved to fit this answer.
- `__latent_entropy` is a GCC attribute used (if the necessary plugin is enabled) to [make the function mix some (fixed) entropy into the kernel "global entropy state"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68975713/what-does-latent-entropy-is-used-for-in-c).

You see all these attributes make sense for an initialization function